# template in header not letting me use my class?

Tags: c++, templates

Very new to templates, my professor is terrible at teaching them, so I'm trying to learn it on my own. Watched several videos and I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong. When I take out the templates my entire code compiles but as soon as I add code

//replacing all previous int's to T

```
template <typename T>
class Checks
{
public:
int ispair(vector<T> dvalues);
int flush(Vector<T> dsuits);
int straight(vector<T> dvalues);
int threeofakind(vector<T> dvalues);
int fourofakind(vector<T> dvalues);
int fullhouse(vector<T> dvalues);
Checks(); //didn't include all of header since there's a lot more want to save room
}
```

When I do that I get a bunch of errors (58) when before I had 0. When I try to use my Checks class in another .cpp:

```
Checks ck1;
Checks ck2; //this would be in another class
```

I get this error: Checks no appropriate default constructor available.

Clearly I am doing something wrong with the way I am doing the template, any suggestions or help?

Comment: Well you did not close your class  with };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had 3 issues

- You forgot to add std:: before vector.
- one vector was written Vector instead of vector
- You didn't close your class with };

  ```
  #include <vector>

  template <typename T>
  class Checks {
  public:
      int ispair(std::vector<T> dvalues);
      int flush(std::vector<T> dsuits); //was Vector
      int straight(std::vector<T> dvalues);
      int threeofakind(std::vector<T> dvalues);
      int fourofakind(std::vector<T> dvalues);
      int fullhouse(std::vector<T> dvalues);

  }; //didn'T close the class with };
  ```

** **EDIT** **

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Checks<int> check;
    std::vector<int> v;
    check.ispair(v);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Check.h

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Checks {
public:
    int ispair(std::vector<T> dvalues);
};

template<class T>
int Checks<T>::ispair(std::vector<T> dvalues) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While I do appreciate you looking at my code, if you would have looked at what I wrote I didn't include the entire .h file. Obviously I have to close my class with a ';', I don't need to put std since I am using that namespace already. My issue is more to do with template syntax, all of this already works without my implementation of templates, is more what I meant for my question. Sorry was just trying to clarify, did not mean to sound irrational, just wanted to make it more clear for people.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess since I'm not proficient in CPP, but you when defining your variables, you need to specify the type to the class:

```
Checks<int> ck1;
```